# Magento 2 Get simple product image URL instead of parent image

Tags: magento2, sales-order, product-images

the below code getting parent configurable parent image even if simple, So how to get the simple url also?

```
$_item = $block->getItem();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_item->getProductId());
$productImageUrl = $block->getBaseUrl().'pub/media/catalog/product'.$_product->getImage();
```

Thanks

Comment: Hey Did you find solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
$_item = $block->getItem();
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Type\Configurable')->getParentIdsByChild($_item->getProductId());
if(isset($product[0]))
{
   $parentProductId = $product[0];
   $_product = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($parentProductId);
   $productImageUrl = $block->getBaseUrl().'pub/media/catalog/product'.$_product->getImage();
}
```

Comment: Hi @Kishan Patadia Thank you for sharing with me this code, but unfortunately its not working. Do you have any idea to get current loaded product ID think if i found this way will working fine.

Comment: In which page you are trying to use it ?

Comment: Its order view page

Comment: If frontend or backend ?

Comment: Oh sorry, backend

Comment: What about the SKU instead of ID is this should get right image right?